# Play streaming audio with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, audio-streaming

I tryed to play follwing streams:

1. url: "http://icecast.unitedradio.it/Radio105.mp3", codec: "mp3"
2. url: "http://shoutcast.radio24.it:8000/", codec: "AAC"

using the MediaPlayer of JavaFX.
This is the code:

```
Media media = new Media("http://icecast.unitedradio.it/Radio105.mp3");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
mediaView.setFitHeight(500);
mediaView.setFitWidth(500);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(new Double(1));

root.getChildren().add(mediaView);

Button playButton = new Button();
playButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent>()
{
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent event)
        {
            mediaPlayer.play();
        }
});

root.getChildren().add(playButton);

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

But pressing the playbutton the audio does not play.

Debugging the Media I have found that using one of stream above, in the Locator.init() the contentLength is -1. May be this the reason why it does not play?

Comment: You can use error callbacks to show error messages, have you tried that?
Also, you can launch your program with java options -Djfxmedia.loglevel=DEBUG -Dprism.verbose=true to produce some additional information - it helps to detect system problems like codec failures.

Comment: Debug (0:00:00:476): JFXMedia supported content types:
    audio/x-aiff
    audio/mp3
    audio/mpeg
    audio/x-wav
    video/x-javafx
    video/x-flv
    video/x-fxm
    video/mp4
    audio/x-m4a
    video/x-m4v
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
    audio/mpegurl

Debug (0:00:00:496): Initializing GSTPlatform
Debug (0:00:00:978): CLocator::CLocator()
Debug (0:00:00:979): CLocatorStream::CLocatorStream()
Debug (0:00:00:984): CMedia::CMedia()
Error (0:00:01:070): ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
Error (0:00:01:615): ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID`

Comment: So, looks like you don't have required codec installed. Do you have libavutil54/libavformat54 installed? If you are using Java7, you need older versions: libavutil52/libavformat52.

Comment: ok may be, but why I can listen the audio if I open the url in the browser ?

Comment: JavaFX supports only GStreamer while browser can use any backend.